# Can we create more than one compute column in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on a code where a table has more than one Compute Column. Can we do that?
I have tried following code but It's not working.

```
CREATE TABLE CRM_Doctor_Request_old(
     Id int NULL,[Event_Type_Id] [bit] NULL, 
     Compute_Event_Type AS CASE WHEN Event_Type_Id=1 Then 'Individual' WHEN Event_Type_Id=0 Then 'Group' PERSISTED, 
     CRM_State_Id smallint NULL, 
     Compute_CRM_State AS CASE WHEN CRM_State_Id=1 Then 'Pending' WHEN CRM_State_Id=2 Then 'Approved' WHEN CRM_State_Id=3 Then 'Cancelled' PERSISTED, 
     Service_State_Id smallint NULL, 
     CRM_Service_State AS CASE WHEN Service_State_Id=1 Then 'In queue' WHEN Service_State_Id=2 Then 'In Process' WHEN Service_State_Id=3 Then 'Completed' WHEN Service_State_Id=3 Then 'Cancelled' PERSISTED
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to `END` your cases:

```
CASE WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... END
```

Nothing wrong with multiple compute columns, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Your computed column relies on `Event_Type_Id`, but that isn't in the table definition.